# Ordering functions with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am really confused about callbacks and when to use them vs await or async functions etc.

I have two blocks of code, one calling an API to download a sheet and a second one to do stuff with that newly downloaded sheet. For eg.

```
            function getLatestDriveSheet() {
                /// stuff here should happen first
            };

            function sendFeedbackMails() {
                /// stuff here should happen after the first
            };

            getLatestDriveSheet();
            sendFeedbackMails()
```

Obviously the API call always returns second, what I don't understand is where exactly I should be implementing such a callback. Or, if its even the right kind of route to take.

Do I need to put the getLatestDriveSheet function within the getLatestDriveSheet and create a callback to the getLatestDriveSheet?

Comment: It all depends on what said functions do and how they do it.

Comment: That is exactly what makes it so hard to understand I think.

Answer (score 2):

You could use both aproaches.

With a callback you could do like so

```
function getLatestDriveSheet(callback) {
  /// stuff here should happen first
  var sheet = getTheSheet();
  callback(sheet);
};

function sendFeedbackMails(sheet) {
  /// stuff here should happen after the first
  sendSheet(sheet);
};

getLatestDriveSheet(sendFeedbackMails);
```

or if you can use `async`

```
async function getLatestDriveSheet(sheet) {
  /// stuff here should happen first
  const sheet = await getTheSheet();
  return sheet;
};

function sendFeedbackMails(sheet) {
  /// stuff here should happen after the first
};

async function getSheetAndSendMails() {
  const sheet = await getLatestDriveSheet();
  sendFeedbackMails(sheet);
}

getSheetAndSendMails();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try implement both approaches to see how each differs and behaves in my case. In the first example, what is getTheSheet(); doing? And in the second, again what does await getTheSheet(); do? The async example seems to make more sense weirdly but why the VAR/const sheet? Or is that variable merely defining the callback? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3206244 I'm sorry if that didn't look clear, getTheSheet() is just a placeholder, you want use a function that actually retrives the sheet. The var/const difference is that the async/await construct is only available in ES6 while in previous versions of JS callbacks were commonly used. If you want to retrive something from a web API you can use fetch if your software allows ES6 syntax and constructs (more here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Thank you @Carlo, I read a little about the ES6 syntax but that makes more sense now, so the variable declaration in the first functions are required to return the callbacks function at which point the second block can run? Each eg being called finally by the function calls at the bottom after being added to the call stack previously?

Comment: I dont understand why sendSheet is not defined in the first example above, 
`function getLatestDriveSheet(callback) {
  /// stuff here should happen first
  var sheet = getTheSheet();
  callback(sheet);
};

function sendFeedbackMails(sheet) {
  /// stuff here should happen after the first
  sendSheet(sheet);
};

getLatestDriveSheet(sendFeedbackMails);`

Comment: @user3206244 of course `sendSheet(sheet);` is just a placeholder, I don't know how you want to send it